# Particle Flow along a Curve with Turbulence

Tags: animation, particles, effects, emission

I'd like to replicate the effect in the follwing the picture:

[image]

I did create a curve with a particle flow on it already but I don't know how to make this kind of eruption effect.

[Scene Download](https://we.tl/t-FTw6oONdFF)

Would be nice if someone can me help out.

Comment: If you can maybe share some of your settings we can help you more. Because its mostly about tweaking

Comment: I add a download link to the scene